# Manage npm dependencies by platform

Tags: node.js, npm

I would manage my npm dependencies by the current build platform.

In my `electron` projet, i need to use `7zip-bin` package, with all platform variant : Linux, MAC and Windows (`7zip-bin-mac` and `7zip-bin-win`).

Anyone know how i can install the good package in the current platform ?

Do you think i need to add all variant off `7zip-bin` in my package.json ?
My projet use `npm 5.0.3`.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use package node-7z. This will solve your problem.